# PHP Array to HTML Description List

Tags: php, html

I have some text files input that are formatted like SUBJECT:Description.
The Description could be a sentence, a single word or integer, or a few names, depending on subject.
There is also a varying length in these files, not all have the same number of subjects or types.

I need to format a Descriptive list in HTML sort of like this:

```
<dl>
 <dt> SUBJECT </dt>
 <dd> Description </dd>
</dl>
```

My issue is I am unsure how to really get from my PHP Array to this format.

As I am new to PHP and HTML as a whole, my current implementation looks like this:

My if statement in here was to prevent the line breaks from being added and keep those two specific subjects all on a single line rather than listing it out.

```
foreach ($contentFromFile as $item){
        $temp = explode(":",$item);
        if (strcmp($temp[0],"COLORS") == 0 or strcmp($temp[0],"COUNTRIES") == 0){
            echo $temp[0]." <br>". $temp[1];
        } else {
            echo $temp[0]." ;<br> ".str_replace(',', '<br />', $temp[1])."<br>";
        }
    }
```

This actually outputs fairly well to what I would want, but I need to get that into HTML and im not really sure how you can loop this into HTML as it has no set size or definitive order.

Comment: In order to give an answer you must provide the format of the input data

Comment: You're already outputting some html. Sounds like you just want to output some different html. But yeah without seeing the original data this is a bit tricky.

Comment: Why do you write `strcmp($temp[0],"COLORS") == 0` instead of just `$temp[0] == "COLORS"`?

Comment: It seems like you just need to replace the `<br>` tags with `<dt>` and `<dd>`. What problem are you having?

Comment: Sorry, I am new to the PHP/HTML interactions, I am going off a lot of examples I have seen. You are saying I can just do like echo <dt> for example, and that would be how I properly output HTML?

As for how the input is structured, an example would be 
COLORS:Red strips with blue star
COUNTRIES:Mexico,France,United Kingdom
RATING:45

This input lengths could vary from input file to input file, and could have additional lines such as CITIES or something.

Comment: `can just do like echo <dt>`...yes. you do `echo "<br>` already, so why not? It's just a different piece of html. Html is just text, at the end of the day. Structure your code so the end result is your desired html, with the data in the middle of it in the right places.